# How to change the values of colSpan with toggle buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have total of 7 buttons which toggle hide and show of columns. For example, if button 1 is pressed once it will hide column 1 and if button 1 is again pressed it will show column 1 and the rest 6 buttons perform the same operation.

But is it possible that if I click any one button from the 7 buttons it will change the colspan of a heading cell from 15 to 13, if any 2 buttons are clicked it will then change the colspan to 11 and if any 3 buttons are clicked it will then change the colspan to 9. It works fine till colspan 9, but after that it changes to colspan 8 rather than colspan 7. How can I fix this?

- if any one button is clicked colspan should be 13
- if any two buttons is clicked colspan should be 11
- if any three buttons is clicked colspan should be 9
- if any four buttons is clicked colspan should be 7
- if any five buttons is clicked colspan should be 5
- if any six buttons is clicked colspan should be 3
- if any seven buttons is clicked colspan should be 1

Note: the state of the buttons needs to remain the same even upon page refresh.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/htj53o2u/38/)

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');
  var prevData = [];

  if (localStorage.getItem('prevData')) {
    var prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prevData'));

    if (prevData && prevData.length > 0) {
      prevData.forEach((e) => {
        if (prevData.includes(e)) {
          let $el = $('.col' + e).toggle();
          let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length + 1;
          $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
        }
      })
    }
  }

  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $('.col' + e.target.dataset.targetIndex).toggle();

    if (!(prevData && prevData.length >= 0)) {
      prevData = [];
    }

    var prevIndex = prevData.indexOf(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);

    if (prevIndex >= 0) {
      prevData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    } else {
      prevData.push(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length + 1;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button class="hide" data-target-index="1">1</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="2">2</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="3">3</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="4">4</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="5">5</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="6">6</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="7">7</button>
```

Comment: So you want the colspan of the `<th>` to be equal to the number of table columns that are visible? (Also, please wrap HTML strings in your text with backticks in order to have that HTML show up, for example: "<th>" should become "\`<th>\`".)

Comment: yes `<th>` should be equal to the number of table columns that are visible@DavidThomas

Comment: I've deleted my answer (perhaps temporarily), given I haven't yet worked out why the last of the "group" of `<td>` elements seems to be visible based on different criteria to the others. It's beginning to look like a `<table>` might not be the best way to present the data (but that's beside the point, and probably irrelevant to the problem). I'll come back to it tomorrow, but may I ask if your HTML can be adjusted by adding additional attributes to reflect the "group" the `<td>` elements are in, and which `<th>` they're related?

Comment: the first `<th>` is related to the firsts `<td>` in every `<tr>` @DavidThomas

Comment: is it resolved? @aastha

Comment: @JayPatel no not yet

Comment: you can use $([your selector]).attr('colspan',13); for setting colspan @aastha

Comment: Because your last group of columns have one displayed and the other hidden, when the jQuery `toggle()` function is applied to them one is hidden and the other is displayed. It looks like clicking any of the buttons has no effect on the last group, but it does. For example, click button 1, the displayed col1 is hidden, and the hidden col1 is displayed. Click button 1 again and they're reversed. Is this the behavior you're looking for in relation to that last group of columns?

Comment: hi i have updated the question and removed the `dispaly:none <td>` columns @bloodyKnuckles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');
  var prevData = [];

  if (localStorage.getItem('prevData')) {
    var prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prevData'));

    if (prevData && prevData.length > 0) {
      prevData.forEach((e) => {
        let $el = $('.col' + e).toggle();
        let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length + 1;
        $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
      })
      if(prevData && prevData.length==1){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 13);
      }else if(prevData && prevData.length==2){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 11);
      }else if(prevData && prevData.length==3){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 9);
      }else if(prevData && prevData.length==4){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 7);
      }else if(prevData && prevData.length==5){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 5);
      }else if(prevData && prevData.length==6){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 3);
      }else if(prevData && prevData.length==7){
        $headings.prop('colspan', 1);
      }else {
        $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
      }
    }
  }

  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $('.col' + e.target.dataset.targetIndex).toggle();

    if (!(prevData && prevData.length >= 0)) {
      prevData = [];
    }

    var prevIndex = prevData.indexOf(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);

    if (prevIndex >= 0) {
      prevData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    } else {
      prevData.push(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length + 1;
    //colspan condition
    if(prevData && prevData.length==1){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 13);
    }else if(prevData && prevData.length==2){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 11);
    }else if(prevData && prevData.length==3){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 9);
    }else if(prevData && prevData.length==4){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 7);
    }else if(prevData && prevData.length==5){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 5);
    }else if(prevData && prevData.length==6){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 3);
    }else if(prevData && prevData.length==7){
      $headings.prop('colspan', 1);
    }else {
      $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
    }
    
  });
});
```

i have made some change when i added comment //colspan condition please check

Comment: is it working? which column we need to add colspan? @aastha

Comment: Hi thankyou @Jay for answering its working fine but when the page is refreshed and colspan is "7" after refresh the colspan changes to 6 this is happing only in only in colspan 7 case

Comment: sorry i dont understand, can you please explain whole scenario @aastha

Comment: what i am trying to say is its working fine but when `5` buttons are clicked then colspan becomes `colspan = 5` right...but when the page is refreshed the colspan becomes `6` rather than `5` coz the page got refreshed

Comment: @aastha please check, i have added same code for refresh also

Answer (score 1):

I use an array to store the states of all 7 buttons. This makes it's easy to count how many are toggled on.

Reminder: you do have some columns in `display:none` to begin with.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');
  var prevData = [];
  var buttons = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]  // of booleans

  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    var targetIndex = e.target.dataset.targetIndex
    let $el = $('.col' + targetIndex).toggle();
    buttons[targetIndex-1] = !buttons[targetIndex-1]
    

    var len = buttons.filter(item=>item).length;
    var colspan = 15 - len*2;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button class="hide" data-target-index="1">1</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="2">2</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="3">3</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="4">4</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="5">5</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="6">6</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="7">7</button>
```

For reference, here's the original JS code with this implemented.

```
jQuery($ => {
    let $headings = $('.heading');
    var prevData = [];
    var buttons = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]  // of booleans

    if (localStorage.getItem('prevData')) {
        var prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prevData'));

        if (prevData && prevData.length > 0) {
            prevData.forEach((e) => {
                if (prevData.includes(e)) {
                    let $el = $('.col' + e).toggle();
                    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length + 1;
                    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
                }
            })
        }
    }

    $('.hide').on('click', e => {
        var targetIndex = e.target.dataset.targetIndex
        let $el = $('.col' + targetIndex).toggle();
        buttons[targetIndex - 1] = !buttons[targetIndex - 1]

        if (!(prevData && prevData.length >= 0)) {
            prevData = [];
        }

        var prevIndex = prevData.indexOf(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);

        if (prevIndex >= 0) {
            prevData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
        } else {
            prevData.push(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));

        var len = buttons.filter(item => item).length;
        var colspan = 15 - len * 2;
        $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please help me where to add this code in my above code so that even after the page is refreshed the button state remanins the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from how you set `display:none;` interleaved item of the last `header`

```
<td class="ref">ref</td>
<td class="col1">col1</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col1">col1</td>
<td class="col2">col2</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col2">col2</td>
<td class="col3">col3</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col3">col3</td>
<td class="col4">col4</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col4">col4</td>
<td class="col5">col5</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col5">col5</td>
<td class="col6">col6</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col6">col6</td>
<td class="col7">col7</td>
<td style="display:none;" class="col7">col7</td>
```

This cause the query `$('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length` make abnormal behavior.

You should change `colSpan` calculate formula from:

```
let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length + 1;
```

to

```
let colspan = ($('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length + 7 - 2 * prevData.length) / $headings.length;
```

To deal with this unusual case.

In detail, `$('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length + 7 - 2 * prevData.length`, the `+7` is get back 7 interleaved item you have set `display:none;` and `- 2 * prevData.length` is manual calculate correct
the number of `td:visible`.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');
  var prevData = [];
  if (localStorage.getItem('prevData')) {
    var prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prevData'));
    if (prevData && prevData.length > 0) {
      prevData.forEach((e) => {
        if (prevData.includes(e)) {
          let $el = $('.col' + e).toggle();
          let colspan = ($('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length + 7 - 2 * prevData.length) / $headings.length;
          $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
        }
      })
    }
  }
  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $('.col' + e.target.dataset.targetIndex).toggle();
    if (!(prevData && prevData.length >= 0)) {
      prevData = [];
    }
    var prevIndex = prevData.indexOf(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
    if (prevIndex >= 0) {
      prevData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    } else {
      prevData.push(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
    let colspan = ($('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length + 7 - 2 * prevData.length) / $headings.length;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td style="display:none" class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button class="hide" data-target-index="1">1</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="2">2</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="3">3</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="4">4</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="5">5</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="6">6</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="7">7</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an array of boolean values representing the display state of each column number.

Adding a click event handler to each button, using its `textContent` value to determine which columns it applies to. In the click handler function block, locating each column associated with that button and toggle its display state.

Also calculating the required `TH` `colspan` value based on the display state of the first occuring column# associated with that button. Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the display state array, `prevData`, and converting `false` into span 0 columns, and `true` into span 2 columns. Adding each one returns the total numbered columns needed to span. The colspan total is initiated with the value 1 since that is the minimum colspan value, due to the leading "ref" column before each group.

Once the colspan is determine, locating and iterating each `TH` tag and updating its colspan value.

Finally, updating the column display state array, `prevData` with the current column display state.

```js
// set and store default display state of each column#: 1 - 7
let prevData = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false];

// iterate buttons
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(btn => {

  // add click handler
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
    // locate and iterate columns associated with button
    document.querySelectorAll(".col" + parseInt(btn.textContent)).forEach(col => {
    
      // toggle the display
      col.style.display = ("none" === col.style.display) ? "table-cell" : "none";
    });
    
    // calculate TH colspan based on display status of each column number: 1 - 7
    let csp = prevData.reduce((csp, colhide, idx) =>
      csp + ((null === document.querySelector('.col' +
        (idx + 1) + ':not([style*="display: none;"])')) ? 0 : 2),
      1); // minimum colspan = 1
      
    // locate TH and iterate, assigning updated colspan to each
    document.querySelectorAll(".heading").forEach(hdg => {
      hdg.colSpan = csp;
    });
    
    // store column display state for column# associated with button
    prevData[parseInt(btn.textContent) - 1] =
      (("none" === document.querySelector(".col" + btn.textContent).style.display) ? true : false);
  });
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="15">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="8">abcd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="ref">ref</td>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button class="hide" data-target-index="1">1</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="2">2</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="3">3</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="4">4</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="5">5</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="6">6</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="7">7</button>
```

Here is the code including `localStorage`:

```
// set and store default display state of each column#: 1 - 7
let prevData = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false];

// check for localStorage
if (null !== localStorage.getItem('prevData')) {
  prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prevData'));
  if (prevData && 0 < prevData.length) {

    // update columns and calculate colspan from saved data
    let csp = 1;
    prevData.forEach((colhide, idx) => {

      // update each column display status
      document.querySelectorAll(".col" + (idx + 1)).forEach(col => {
        col.style.display = (false === colhide) ? "table-cell" : "none";
      });

      // increment colspan
      csp += ((false !== colhide) ? 0 : 2);
    });

    // locate and iterate TH, assigning colspan
    document.querySelectorAll(".heading").forEach(hdg => {
      hdg.colSpan = csp;
    });
  }
} 

// if no localStorage, save one
else {
  localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
}

// iterate buttons
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(btn => {

  // add click handler
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
    // locate and iterate columns associated with button
    document.querySelectorAll(".col" + parseInt(btn.textContent)).forEach(col => {
    
      // toggle the display
      col.style.display = ("none" === col.style.display) ? "table-cell" : "none";
    });
    
    // calculate TH colspan based on display status of each column number: 1 - 7
    let csp = prevData.reduce((csp, colhide, idx) =>
      csp + ((null === document.querySelector('.col' +
        (idx + 1) + ':not([style*="display: none;"])')) ? 0 : 2),
      1); // minimum colspan = 1
      
    // locate TH and iterate, assigning updated colspan to each
    document.querySelectorAll(".heading").forEach(hdg => {
      hdg.colSpan = csp;
    });
    
    // store column display state for column# associated with button
    prevData[parseInt(btn.textContent) - 1] =
      (("none" === document.querySelector(".col" + btn.textContent).style.display) ? true : false);

    localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
  });
});
```